# How to find unread sms messages in windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, sms

I need to find if there are any unread SMS on a windows mobile 6 smartphone.

I know about message interception, but thats not what I need: I already know if I receive an sms, but now I need to know if there is an unread sms at some later point in time (which might not be, since the user might have read the sms by then).

My goal is to emulate a sms reminder function: if you received an sms while you where absent, it will give a reminder signal every 15 (or so) minutes, so you don't have keep looking at your phone all the time.
Other mobile phones already contain this functionality, but in windows mobile it is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SystemState.MessagingSmsUnread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.messagingsmsunread.aspx) property. This will give you the number of unread messages, but no more details.

Comment: Great, that will do nicely! Thanks!